# CPU reach 100% in in 200 request per second in iis 8.5

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, autofac, cpu-usage, iis-8.5

**App hosted in IIS 8.5 on dedicated server with configuration dual xeon E5 2620 v2, 64 GB Ram, 1 TB HDD.**

Server Technolgy : **Web api 2, Angular js, Entity framework 6.0, SQL server 2014.**
Client Side : **web browser with angularjs and android mobile app which call web api method using http request.**
Extra Tools : Autofac 3.5, Automapper, newtonsoft json,
after refering some post, we have remove automapper from continuous calling method.

whenever there are **100 user** will be online cpu consume almost **100%**. i have tried so many debugger application, performance monitor, and try to get solution but no luck, i have generate some report which function couse problem. as per some debuging tools i got below result, plz see below image.

[image: debugdiag, Thread used Max CPU.]

[image: as per lean sentry its gives result]

but still not identify problem,

we have hosted app and see this problem, we think its some coding problem and optimization. so we have started to optimize app and update it dailly base in server and see again usage, but there are no any better performance.

as per user request, per user it will get **2 request per second** and one input operation which is not on continue based. may be its in minute or more.

after **100 user** start above operation **cpu reach on 99% to 100%,** and when user increased app become slow, when 100 user are there, one request complete in about **500ms to 800ms**. after 200 user are there it will complete in **2 sec to 4 sec.** and its become slower and slower.

**as per one frnd which has also same application, same user request, they have published on VPS, and they are 2000 user are working at a time still not down, as per comparison with them, i have dedicated server and no resource devide to any one. so i think i will get more enough performance then my frnd**

**as per some expert frnds advice, its block some request, may be in EF or iis.
but how and why. there are all code are as usual.**

I hope i will get solution as soon as possible, now its a headeach problem for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have so many tools constantly monitoring your server impacting throughput.. Try to uninstall them from the production environment. Ideally such tools are not recommended on live environment but you can install on test environments.

Also please mention how you are testing 100 or 200 requests?, Which tools you using to send 100-200 requests?

Comment: I am not using any tools for 200 request, there are live clients which are using it, and i am just get information about online clients.

Answer (score -1):

With no doubts your hardware and your stack can handle thousands of active users. Removing Automapper was not a move you should have considered first.

For the mentioned stack the most obvious issue is usually the ORM used without thinking of underlying database. Lazy loading, SELECT N+1 problem and so on the classic list. The best way to tackle this sort of issues is to use some profiling tools. Start with SQL Server Profiler and see how many database requests you have. You might want to use [EFProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf) to find out if you have too many database requests per session, usually you should have just one or two, no matter how many elements your API call returns. If you eventually find out that the number of database calls in one session correlates with the number of elements returned by the API call, you have [SELECT N+1](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/Products/EFProf/learn/Alert/SelectNPlusOneInTheSameRequest).

If you see that the number of database queries is low and constant per session, you can start looking at the database itself, analysing execution plans and adding indices.

As you can understand from my answer, I suspect that the database is probably an issue. However, don't get to the "let's change the database" trap since although I am not a big SQL Server fan, I know that this database is capable to do a lot and do it fast. Hundred users is a funny load to kick off the SQL Server. So it is most probably how your code works with it and it will be exactly the same with any other database if you don't start looking at your own code and stop blaming your stack.

You can also try isolating the issue by splitting your web server and SQL Server to two different machines.